# Changing file timestamps on windows correctly?

Tags: windows, api, timestamp

I'm trying to change the file create time of a file through the windows API, but the dates I input into the functions end up being off by a day or so, and the time (hour and minutes) are off by a few hours.

How do I account for timezones and daylight savings etc? Or rather, how do I set the exact date-time I specify without windows adjusting the times

code being used is as follows:

```
    SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
    GetSystemTime(&sysTime);

    sysTime.wDay = d;
    sysTime.wMonth = m;
    sysTime.wYear = y;
    sysTime.wHour = h;
    sysTime.wMinute = min;
    sysTime.wSecond = s;
    sysTime.wMilliseconds = ms;

    FILETIME fTime;
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&sysTime,&fTime);

    SetFileTime(fHandle, &fTime, NULL, NULL);   // Create Time
```

For example if I specify the time of a file to be  ***1/3/2015 21:57*** through the program, and check the timestamp of the file after via file properties, the time shows up as ‎***March ‎02, ‎2015, ‏‎10:57:12 AM***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically correct. The application usually works with UTC time (`GetSystemTime`), it only needs local-time conversion when it's showing the time to user.

In case you really need to input local-time, then use `TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime` to convert local-time to UTC-time.

```
SYSTEMTIME local_time, system_time;
GetLocalTime(&local_time);

local_time.wHour = 2;//user input
...

TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(NULL, &local_time, &system_time);

FILETIME file_time;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&system_time, &file_time);
SetFileTime(h, &file_time, NULL, NULL);
```

Otherwise just use `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime` to show data/time to the user.